# Mautic email links getting replaced leading to broken links

Tags: mautic

I tried adding a url to to my Mautic emails. They are getting replaced by the following links which appears to be broken and is triggering Gmail spam filters.

http://url9156.motivesmedia.in/ls/click?upn=r1I3730w6uT5Y-2F1VS0EcEa6mVXyfIdORD1s4GHTFFGmFiirbW6nwIfkY6YGDQ4R-2B53sf0qOqcp1sMdeFmWbCPQ9IR2WbGVz7om2qClGMZ3H2jb-2BMYi10Cs4PIMVw-2BVCIVhIYDnmhf3sVkz9mxgcGALJQPWRFJm8-2FscN0sIbzITKqzKvFR3gAIUBXTDUsgN-2BVo6BYeB40YHYHS6soAu-2BendJzCPiH4ZdolH7v-2BxflDJtXqlHyjQlS5rtC-2Bdez3HbprER9j29g43oQGbQI7kr2cmf4y6Wb0MP-2BOZcmLc1j6SPxz9pOW0raMmyRInuXvrPM3CkgXC5DXqCDBcuVm3bVnaO8FLQpv1n590vO2sY2r9Lw7-2FyLTP9T2D-2FjXGzHD8vbRcmpQxXOg0ae-2BrEJ2RcZrA-3D-3D8LJs_JZHjo7Iyk6KmIbqvM4N7ab34zxuAK4n5HtR9OHOpxkngg7afD-2FZ2jVRmLFUmgoUskyBbE3Bi-2F9OO534waDayFbPUopg6tOQCst7vXZtbzcRBkET0dtqJ9gpbZap6lV8kJwSB6A3uktLZOKUYH5yxhy7cXkbbHf06zILRskCpPoSUZRIZRAZe5h-2Fgq8-2B2t-2BUA2n1YgKKrhMwmz61v0nfrra-2B50gwmSykieNdRVWRxFeE-3D

The original url is a google drive file. The problem is that when I add a link in my email it always ends up in the spam and when the recipient clicks the link, it's showing a site not found error (Please click the above replaced url to understand what I'm trying to say). When I don't add any links, it ends up in the inbox without any problem.

I have installed mautic on a subdomain mautic.mydomain.com and the root url is given as mautic.mydomain.com (I've tried changing the root url to mydomain.com and clearing the cache but that didn't help.)

Here's a screenshot showing the broken links.
[screenshot of broken links in email-tester](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGKsi.png)

There are no log errors being shown.

Please tell me why this is happening and any solution to this problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

## Link Tracking Config

Link Tracking in Mautic properly working depends on a few things:

- Your hosting configuration
- Use of third-party Queues like RabbitMQ or Elasticbeanstalk
- If using LAMP, appropriate .htaccess file.
- If using LEMP, appropriate nginx.conf.

Because the setup for infrastructure so widely varies, it is difficult to troubleshoot your question without more details.

## Spam Score

Mautic will automatically replace your links with a link through the Mautic platform in order to track clicks.

If you want to decrease your spam score, you should look into the following:

1. Mautic should be on the same domain you are sending emails from... otherwise it will always look spammy.
2. Set up SPF / DKIM On your domain.
3. Reduce the number of links in your email. Too many and it can get a higher spam score.

Comment: Well the problem is not actually with the spam score. The email reaches the inbox if I don't add in any links.I think it's the trackable link replaced by the Mautic that's causing the problem. The link appears broken when the recipients click it and it shows an error message 'page not found'( Please click the url on the question to see what I'm trying to say.) Is there any way to stop Mautic from replacing this links so that they would actually do the purpose they are intended to do. I tried disabling link tracking from config<edit but that didn't solve the problem.

Comment: There is a problem with your Mautic configuration then. Are you getting any errors in your logs that you can share when the link is clicked?

Comment: I updated my answer to explain the difficulties with link tracking